# Add Records to Recordset / Add fields to table

Tags: ms-access, vba, dao, recordset

Objective:

1. Allow the user to create a custom table with X defined fields
2. Allow the user to input field names

Right now, the code is able to create a table with 1 column. The idea is to allow the user to create a custom table with x defined fields and also allow the user to define the field names.

The table name is stored in ExportName.
The column name is stored in Field1

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim tbl As DAO.TableDef
Dim fld As DAO.Field2
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset2
Dim i As Integer

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set tbl = dbs.CreateTableDef(Me.ExportName)

Set fld = tbl.CreateField(Field1, dbInteger)
tbl.Fields.Append fld
dbs.TableDefs.Append tbl
```

Given the above objectives, what is an efficient way to set up a loop that reads the different field inputs?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You make a form that allows them to enter in the field names and types as well as the table name and then from that form you generate the table, much as you are doing here. What specific question do you have?

Comment: Make a loop creating fields as long as the user input values.

Comment: Yes exactly, the form is actually set up; however, I'm just looking for guidance on how to set up that loop creating fields.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you already have a 'temp' table (table is permanent but records are temporary) to save user input of field names and types. Open a recordset of those records and loop through recordset. If this is a split database and you want table created in backend, code must set connection to backend, create table, set table link. Example from my db below.

Constant gstrBasePath is declared in a general module header. It is path to folder that holds the frontend and backend files:
`Global Const gstrBasePath = "\\servername\folderpath\"`

```
Private Sub tbxTestNum_AfterUpdate()

Dim td As TableDef

'check if test table already exists in backend
For Each td In DBEngine.OpenDatabase(gstrBasePath & "\Data\LabData.accdb").TableDefs
    If td.Name = Me.tbxTestNum Then
        MsgBox "Data table for this test already exists in the backend."
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next td
Me.DataField.SetFocus
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec

End Sub


Private Sub btnBuild_Click()

On Error GoTo err_Proc

Dim tdf As TableDef
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim db As DAO.Database

CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM BuildTable WHERE DataField <> 'LabNum' AND DataField <> 'method'"

If IsNull(Me.tbxTestNum) Then
    MsgBox "Must enter test number.", vbCritical, "Error"
Else
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    'connect to the backend database
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source='" & gstrBasePath & "Data\LabData.accdb'"
    'create the test table
    cn.Execute "CREATE TABLE " & Me.tbxTestNum & " (LabNum text(12) PRIMARY KEY Not Null, method text(30) Not Null);"

    'set table link
    Set tdf = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef(Me.tbxTestNum)
    tdf.SourceTableName = Me.tbxTestNum
    tdf.Connect = "; DATABASE=" & gstrBasePath & "Data\LabData.accdb"
    CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append tdf

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open "SELECT * FROM BuildTable;", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockPessimistic
    'must use DAO to set AllowZeroLength property, I don't allow zero length fields and Access defaults to Yes
    Set db = DBEngine.OpenDatabase(gstrBasePath & "Data\LabData.accdb")
    While Not rs.EOF
        If rs!DataField <> "LabNum" And rs!DataField <> "method" Then
            'create field in new table
            cn.Execute "ALTER TABLE " & Me.tbxTestNum & " ADD COLUMN " & _
                        rs!DataField & " " & IIf(rs!DataType = "Boolean", "Bit", rs!DataType) & _
                        IIf(rs!DataType = "Text", "(" & rs!FieldSize & ")", "") & ";"
        End If
        If rs!DataType = "Text" Then
            'change the AllowZeroLength default Yes to No
            db.TableDefs(Me.tbxTestNum).Fields(rs!DataField).AllowZeroLength = False
        ElseIf rs!DataType = "Number" Then
            'make sure number field DefaultValue not set to 0
            db.TableDefs(Me.tbxTestNum).Fields(rs!DataField).DefaultValue = ""
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend

    rs.Close
    cn.Close
    db.Close

End If

Me.tbxTestNum.SetFocus

Exit_proc:
    Exit Sub

err_Proc:
    MsgBox "Error encountered in AddDataTable procedure btnBuild_Click - " & Err & " : " & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_proc

End Sub
```

If there are multiple users allowed to run this process, place this table in frontend or save records with user ID and then open recordset filtered to that ID. Also, the DELETE action would have to include this filter.

However, I do not recommend implementing code that allows users to modify db design.